# Absolute path to file outside of project folder with getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, file-io, getresource

I want to create jar which will read txt fom jar and then save txt file to user.home folder. When it is runned again, it will read file from user.home.

I read file like this:

```
if(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+System.getProperty("user.home")+"/"+file_name) == null){
            configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(file_name);
        } else {
            configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(System.getProperty("user.home")+ "/"+file_name);
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(configStream));
```

And then I write to file like this:

```
try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.home")+ "/" + file_name));
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                if (((Block) (listArray.get(i).get(j))).getState() == blockState.blank) {
                    out.write("0");
                } else if (((Block) (listArray.get(i).get(j))).getState() == blockState.solid) {
                    out.write("1");
                } else if (((Block) (listArray.get(i).get(j))).getState() == blockState.player) {
                    out.write("I");
                } else if (((Block) (listArray.get(i).get(j))).getState() == blockState.spikes) {
                    out.write("^");
                } else if (((Block) (listArray.get(i).get(j))).getState() == blockState.water) {
                    out.write("~");
                } else if (((Block) (listArray.get(i).get(j))).getState() == blockState.transparent) {
                    out.write("T");
                }
            }
            out.write("\n");
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't know why, but program never read file from user.home, it always reads one from project folder. Where am I making a mistake? Thanks

Comment: How do you save the txt to user.home ? Your code does not include the saving part.

Comment: Are you sure that the loop is actually executed? Try write something outside the loop.

Comment: Why are you trying to read a file from the file system as a resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) on locations that are not within the JVM classpath. The following snippet works because somewhere within your JVM classpath the `file_name` exists.

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream(file_name);
```

What you are attempting to do here in the next snippet is to use the current class's classloader to load a file that may or may not be part of the JVM classpath.

```
configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(System.getProperty("user.home")+ "/"+file_name);
```

The relative root node from which this path will be traversed can also not be controller. Use a `FileInputStream` and load the file from an absolute path like `/usr/local/file_name` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't realised that solution is that simple. I switched to getResourceAsStream from FileInputStream because of exception that was occuring after running program from jar.